# More efficient way to aggregate and re-columnize results?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a query that aggregates a bunch of data into nice, readable columns from a fairly chaotic WP set of "wp_postmeta".  Unfortunately, it's *really* slow, I'm pretty sure due to the "LIKE '%whatever%' in there.  Unfortunately, I need to test for the presence of a string among many possibilities. s there a faster way to get these results? Additionally, I'd love to NOT have to iterate through my results looking for information that's related to a single field from another area -  rather, I'd like to tie that info in during THIS query. The query is below, followed by my desired tie-in:

```
SELECT post_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'size' THEN meta_value END) size,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'image1' THEN meta_value END) image1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'image2' THEN meta_value END) image2

       FROM wp_postmeta  WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id from wp_postmeta 
       WHERE meta_key='location' AND meta_value LIKE '%Run Of Site%') 
       GROUP BY post_id
```

Which returns a beautifully-readable result, like this, but VERY slowly:

```
   Post_id   |   size      |   image1     |   image2
    ----------|-------------|--------------|-------------
    6528      |   Large     |    6507      |    6508
```

Now the tie-in.  The fields, "image1", "image2", etc, present a single id number each. That id is the post_id of an image attachment, which has a url in another place.  For example, if "image1" presented meta_value '6507', then the URL associated would be in the database elsewhere.

So, the original "image1" is like this:

```
meta_id   |   post_id   |   meta_key   |   meta_value
----------|-------------|--------------|-------------
51520     |   6543      |    image1    |    6507
51521     |   6543      |    image2    |    6508
```

The URL for image1, (6507) comes from elsewhere, like this:

```
meta_id   |   post_id   |   meta_key    |   meta_value
----------|-------------|---------------|-------------
51518     |   6507      | attached_file |   KS1.gif
51519     |   6508      | attached_file |   KS2.gif
```

So, What I'd REALLY like to figure out is how to combine my query properly for (a) speed, and (b) to not have to do a second query, iterating through for URLs.

So my result would look like this:

```
Post_id   |   size      |   image1     |   image2
----------|-------------|--------------|-------------
6528      |   Large     |    KS1.gif   |   KS2.gif
```

Comment: Just to check, try removing the LIKE bit

Answer (score 0):

You're  combining two different techniques here - which I guess is fine... but a little odd. In practice, a third method will (I think) be fractionally faster, but the performance killer is always going to be that '%' at the beginning of your like condition. It prevents the use of an index.

But before we get on to the faster method, let's try these...

```
SELECT m.post_id
     , MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'size'   THEN m.meta_value END) size
     , MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'image1' THEN m.meta_value END) image1
     , MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'image2' THEN m.meta_value END) image2
  FROM wp_postmeta m
  JOIN wp_postmeta n
    ON n.post_id = m.post_id
 WHERE n.meta_key = 'location' 
   AND n.meta_value LIKE '%Run Of Site%'
 GROUP 
    BY m.post_id


SELECT m.post_id
     , MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'size'   THEN m.meta_value END) size
     , MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'image1' THEN m.meta_value END) image1
     , MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'image2' THEN m.meta_value END) image2
     , MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'location' THEN m.meta_value END) location
  FROM wp_postmeta m
 GROUP 
    BY m.post_id
HAVING m.location LIKE '%Run Of Site%';
```

Comment: Strange - the 1st query gets a nice fast result, but image1 and image 2 are blank - query #2 is a little bit slower than the first - both are faster than mine, but neither gets image values...

Comment: !?!?! Can we see an sqlfiddle?

Comment: possibly - there are thousands of records in this thing - and I haven't time to create new content - I have a client waiting, and my brain is toast from 4 days of 20-hour-per-day coding...